# Is there a way to expand an array like a struct in Pyspark? Star does not work

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame with the following nesting in Pyspark:

```
>content: struct
   importantId: string
   >data: array
      >element: struct
         importantCol0: string
         importantCol1: string
```

I need the following output:

| importantId | importantCol0 | importantCol1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10800005 | 0397AZ | 0397AZ |
| 10800006 | 0397BZ | 0397BZ |

I tried the following code:
 `df1 = df0.select(F.col('content.*'))`

I got:

| importantId | data |
| --- | --- |
| 10800005 | {importantCol0: 0397AZ, importantCol1: 0397AZ} |
| 10800006 | {importantCol0: 0397BZ, importantCol1: 0397BZ} |

I followed with:

`df2 = df1.select(F.col('importantId'), F.col('data.*')`

but I get the following error:

`AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(data).`

Does anyone know how to fix this? I was expecting a way to expand an array like a struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use `inline` to explode array of structs to columns and rows

```
result = df.select('*', F.inline('data')).drop('data')
```

Example,

```
df.show()

+------------+--------------------+
|importantCol|                data|
+------------+--------------------+
|           1|    [{1, 2}, {4, 3}]|
|           2|[{10, 20}, {40, 30}]|
+------------+--------------------+

result.show()

+------------+-------------+-------------+
|importantCol|importantCol0|importantCol1|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|           1|            1|            2|
|           1|            4|            3|
|           2|           10|           20|
|           2|           40|           30|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```